# ¿Como saber si mi clave es RSA de 2048 bits o como generar una?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, keystore

Ase poco perdí mi clave que se utiliza para seguir actualizando mi apk en la **play store** solicite ayuda con el soporte de play console.

### Primera opción

Para darle solución a mi problema tengo que **generar una nueva clave**, lo intente realizar con **Androi Studio**. Siguiendo la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#generate-key) pero al dar **Ok** me aparece el siguiente mensaje de alerta.

> Key was created with errors:
>
> Warning: El almacén de claves JKS utiliza un formato propietario. Se
>   recomienda migrar a PKCS12, que es un formato estándar del sector que
>   utiliza "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore
>   **Path**\update-keystore.jks -destkeystore **Path**\update-keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

El cual no se si me genera ya como me lo solicita la **asistencia de Google** el cual dice que **Esta clave debe ser una clave RSA de 2048 bits y tienen validez de 25 años.**

- ¿Como valido si mi clave generada es **RSA de 2048 bits**?

---

### Otra opción dada por la asistencia de **Google**

Es que utilice los siguientes comandos para generarlo

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

**Cuando lo intente utilizar entrando a la ruta del  `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin>` ejecutando lo siguiente.**

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Trabajo\Proyecto\resourse\almacen-de-claves\keystore.jks'
```

muestra el siguiente mensaje

> Opción no permitida:  con keytool -genkeypair [OPTION]...

Comment: Estás usando el comando incorrecto. Edité mi pregunta para responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre el warning de jks, es simplemente eso, una advertencia porque jks es un formato que no se recomienda. La solución al warning es que, cuando sigues el paso de la documentación que dice

> Keystore
>
> - Key store path: Select the location where your keystore should be created.

cambies el keystore path de salida para que sea PKS12 (`upload-keystore.pks12`). También puedes cambiar el formato del keystore que ya tienes

```
keytool -importkeystore \
    -srckeystore keystore.jks \
    -destkeystore keystore.p12 \
    -deststoretype PKCS12 \
    -srcalias <jkskeyalias> \
    -deststorepass <password> \
    -destkeypass <password>
```

**Edito**: Para generar el certificado, el comando es

```
keytool -genkey -alias <desired certificate alias> 
-keystore <path to keystore.pfx>
-storetype PKCS12 
-keyalg RSA 
-storepass <password> 
-validity 9125 
-keysize 2048
```

Para saber cómo está definida tu llave privada, revisa el contenido del keystore

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ../path/de/tu/archivo/upload-keystore.jks -alias myalias
```

La herramienta keytool viene con el JDK, así que allí deberías encontrarle. El `alias` debe ser el que le pusiste a tu llave privada en ese mismo formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible ver la longitud de la llave usando `openssl`

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -text -noout
```

Y para ésto, habría que exportar primero la llave desde el keystore

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12  -nodes -nocerts -out key.pem
```

O también podrías usar [keystore-explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/)

Comment: intente crear el `pks12` pero me manda el siguiente mensaje en consola `Opción no permitida:  \
keytool -importkeystore [OPTION]...`

Comment: Ponlo todo en una sola línea sin los backslashes :)

Comment: Funciono lo anterior y comprobe si mi clave es **RSA**. Actualice mi pregunta ya que con lo que proporsionas para generar la key como me lo indican al utilizar `-genkeypair ` me manda lo mismo **opcion no permitida**